# Accessing variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say i'm building my own command-line and I would like to have access to and even change any variable defined normally in NodeJS. I would have the name of the variable defined in another variable that would be called `cmd[1]`. After a decent time researching, I have come to a conclusion that there is no global object that holds all the defined variables. How can I return the data of a variable that is described in another variable? Here is a little code block explaining what i'm trying to achieve:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: 'CMD> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  var commandl = line.trim();
  var cmd = commandl.split(' ');

  switch(cmd[0]) {
    case 'vr':
      //here i'd like to log the variable which name is in cmd[1]. if there was a global object i would assume i could just global[cmd[1]].
      break;
    case 'spit':
      //here i'd like to log an object with every defined variables and its live changes
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`${line.trim()}: command not found`);
      break;
  }
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
```

There's got to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Waseem I. has pointed out that this only works in REPL.

---

But I'm keeping it here for posterity.

---

In Node.js, the equivalent to `window` is `global`. For example:

```
> var a = 2;
> global.a // == 2
```

This contains every global variable (including system ones like `process`) and ones you define (as seen above).

Comment: This does not apply to scripts, only REPL.

Comment: Hrm. That's strange, I would have thought I've used in before (I just tested it now; it doesn't work)

Comment: I read that if I just define variables without `var` (`variable = 123`) then it would display in global (`global['variable']`) but i'm not sure how reliable that is and how different it is to `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a `store` and use that?

**store.js**

```
// store.js 
module.exports = {}
```

**app.js**

```
// app.js
var store = require('./store');
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: 'CMD> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  var commandl = line.trim();
  var cmd = commandl.split(' ');

  switch(cmd[0]) {
    case 'vr':
      store.vr = cmd[1];
      //here i'd like to log the variable which name is in cmd[1]. if there was a global object i would assume i could just global[cmd[1]].
      break;
    case 'spit':
      store.spit = '...';'
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`${line.trim()}: command not found`);
      break;
  }
  rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
```

**other.js**

```
// other.js
var store = require('./store');

console.log(store.vr);
```

While you can use `global` but this method is recommended because you can easily mock the store for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to store variables, but if i wanted to do that i could just use `global`. Plus it would interfere with my natural coding habits and its not something i look forward doing for a huge project. Either way if this is impossible i might have to.